# Insert Into Binary Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

/* Update */

The insertNode function is not properly working and will not let me verify if the root != NULL. When the program breaks, it shows me that it is happening @insertNode(), line: "if (ptr->left == NULL){ // create new node @ left." Just after the "if(s.length() > 0)" statement.

/* End Update */

I need help with inserting nodes into my binary tree. The tree is supposed to be "like" a hoffman tree, to where the root node does not store any value. The children nodes will all store a character in them though.

The main will create a new tree, read in a txt file of morse code "a .-" line by line, and insert each rows character into it's corresponding node within the tree.

Ex. the code for the letter 'a' = ".-" which will put the node containing 'a' at the tree position root->left->right.

My main problem is with initializing the tree as not NULL. I left the insert function blank, because it's wrapper should initialize the tree's root as a node, yet it is not initializing it. When I run main, it reads the file, attempts to insert, and then checks if the tree is empty. After every line read and "supposed to be" inserted, the tree.empty check always returns 1.

How can I get this working?

main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "morse_tree.h"
using namespace std;

string encode(string s);
string decode(string s);

int main(void){
    char letter, w = '\0';
    string code, s;

    Morse_Code tree1; 
    cout << tree1.empty() << endl;
    ifstream morseFile("morse_code.txt");
    if (morseFile.is_open()){
        while (morseFile >> letter >> code){
            cout << letter << ": " << code << endl;
            tree1.insert(letter, code);
            cout << tree1.empty() << endl;
        }
        morseFile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "could not open file: " << endl;
    cout << "PRINT TREE IN PRE ORDER" << endl; 
    tree1.printPreOrder();
    cout << tree1.empty() << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

morse_tree.h file:

```
#ifndef _MORSE_TREE_H_
#define _MORSE_TREE_H_
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std; 

class Morse_Code {

private:
    struct TreeNode{
        char letter;
        TreeNode* left;
        TreeNode* right;
        TreeNode(char c, TreeNode* l, TreeNode* r){
            letter = c; 
            l = NULL; 
            r = NULL; 
        }
    };
    TreeNode* root;
    void preOrder(TreeNode* ptr);
    void insertNode(TreeNode* p, string s, char c);

public:
    Morse_Code();
    Morse_Code(char c, string s);
    ~Morse_Code(); 
    bool empty()const;
    void insert(const char c, string s);
    void printPreOrder();
};
#endif
```

morse_tree.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "morse_tree.h"
#include<string>

using namespace std; 


Morse_Code::Morse_Code(){
    root = NULL; 
}

Morse_Code::~Morse_Code(){
    delete root;
}
bool Morse_Code::empty()const{
    return (root == NULL);
}
void Morse_Code::insert(char c, string s){
    if (root == NULL){
        root = new TreeNode('1', NULL, NULL);
    }
    insertNode(root, s, c);
}
void Morse_Code::insertNode(TreeNode* ptr, string s, char c){
    if (root == NULL){
        root = new TreeNode('\0', NULL, NULL);
    }
    if (s == ""){
        ptr->letter = c;
        return; 
    }
    if (s.length() > 0){
        if (ptr->left == NULL){ // create new node @ left
            ptr->left = new TreeNode('1', NULL, NULL);
        }
        if (ptr->right == NULL){ // create new node @ right
            ptr->right = new TreeNode('1', NULL, NULL);
        }
        if (s.at(0) == '.'){
            ptr = ptr->left;
        }
        if (s.at(0) == '-'){
            ptr = ptr-> right; 
        }
    }
    insertNode(ptr, s.substr(1), c);
}

void Morse_Code::printPreOrder(){
    preOrder(root);
}
void Morse_Code::preOrder(TreeNode* ptr){
    if (ptr != NULL) {  
        cout << ptr->letter << " ";    
        preOrder(ptr->left);
        preOrder(ptr->right);  
    }
}
```

morse_code.txt file:

```
a .-
b -...
c -.-.
d -..
e .
f ..-.
g --.
h ....
i ..
j .---
k -.-
l .-..
m --
n -.
o ---
p .--.
q --.-
r .-.
s ...
t -
u ..-
v ...-
w .--
x -..-
y -.--
z --..
```

Comment: `because it's wrapper should initialize the tree's root as a node, yet it is not initializing it`  Well, if you don't show us your code that you attempted, then of course the function doesn't do anything -- you left it empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code never creates the `root` of `Morse_Code`, instead it creates a new tree node on every call to `insert`. The edited code below should fix your problem.

```
void Morse_Code::insert(char c, string s){
    if (root == NULL){
         root = new TreeNode('1', NULL, NULL);
    }
    insertNode(root, s, c);
 }
```

Comment: That seemed to get me past where I was at. Thank you.

Comment: will do as soon as I get past inserting the first node and verify the tree isn't empty/NULL.